# Swift 2 - Use case for using break on if statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement, break, swift2

Swift 2's guide mentions that you can end program execution of an if statement. I personally have never used break with if-statement.

> A break statement ends program execution of a loop, an if statement,
>   or a switch statement...When a break statement is followed by the
>   name of a statement label, it ends program execution of the loop, if
>   statement, or switch statement named by that label.

In what situation would one be using break in an if-statement? This language feature seems useless.

```
TEST:
if (true) {
    break TEST
}
```

Comment: The only case I can think of you would do that in is using break inside an if statement inside a loop... But you do that in all other languages.

Comment: In that case, it's still breaking out of a loop, not an if-statement.  I fail to see the value of the ability to break out of an if-statement.

Comment: @Boon I can't think of one either. Every possible use I can rewrite more elegantly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using break with an if statement seems a bit contrived, and I can't think of a place where style would demand it.  It does, however, save an extra level of indentation when skipping the latter portion of an if statement in an if-else clause, which can be useful for deeply nested loops.

In other languages, a popular (and/or controversial) idiom is to use labels for handling errors in deeply nested functions.  For example, one might want to break out of a loop on error, like this:

```
func testBreak3() {
    // doesn't compile!!!
    let a = false, b = true, x = 10, y = 20, err = true
    if !a {
        if b && x > 0 {
            if y < 100 {
                if err {
                    break handleError
                }
                // some statements
            } else {
                // other stuff
            }

        }
    }
    return  // avoid error handling

    handleError:
    print("error")
    // handle the error
}
```

But in Swift (I'm using 2.0 as a reference), labels are different than with other languages; the above example doesn't compile for two reasons:  The label isn't declared yet when it's used, and the label must be directly associated with a `do`, `while`, `if`, or `case` statement.  Furthermore, break within an `if` or `do` statements requires that statement to be labeled.  We can fix this as follows, although the changes make the solution less attractive due to additional tracking via the `errorFlagged` variable, making refactoring more attractive:

```
func testBreak() {
    let a = false, b = true, x = 10, y = 20, err = true
    var errorFlagged = false
    nestedIf: if !a {
        if b && x > 0 {
            if y < 100 {
                if err {
                    errorFlagged = true
                    break nestedIf
                }
                // some statements
            } else {
                // other stuff
            }
        }
    }

    // skip handling if no error flagged.
    if errorFlagged {
        print("error")
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why refactoring is more attractive here, and how you might refactor. This solution seems like the cleanest way for me to break out of a check for the presence of a certain deprecated launch option on the basis of an SDK version check. Does that strike you as a situation where style demands this solution?

Comment: @eLillie The solution above does seem fairly well suited to your situation, with what little I know.  Code with lower level of nesting is easier to read, all things considered.  Refactoring might be something to reduce the nesting, such as a function to perform all the checks.  Subject, of course, to all the other concerns like number of parameters to the function, etc.

Answer (score 22):

For example if you want to describe a number (with Strings) with reference to sets of numbers (even/rational/negative numbers) your code could look something like this:

```
if condition1 {
    // code
    if condition2 {
        // code
        if condition3 {
            // code
            if condition4 {
                //code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can achieve the same logic but without the nested ifs by refactoring it (using `guard`):

```
OuterIf: if condition1 {
    // code

    guard condition2 else { break OuterIf }
    // code

    guard condition3 else { break OuterIf }
    // code

    guard condition4 else { break OuterIf }
    // code
}

// reads even better when breaking out of "do"
scope: do {
    guard condition1 else { break scope }
    // code

    guard condition2 else { break scope }
    // code

    guard condition3 else { break scope }
    // code

    guard condition4 else { break scope }
    // code

}
```

You might think that this can also be achieved with `switch` and `fallthrough` but this doesn't work with "normal" cases because it checks all conditions and if one condition is met all following conditions aren't even evaluated.

So the `fallthough` has to be called conditionally.

This does work but I isn't very readable not to mention its "beauty":

```
let x = 4
switch x {
case _ where condition1:
    // code
    if condition2 { fallthrough }
case _ where false:
    // code
    if condition3 { fallthrough }
case _ where false:
    // code
    if condition4 { fallthrough }
case _ where false:
    // code
    break
default: break
}
```

Comment: Nice example - upvoted, though the break is applied towards guard, not if.  Can you think of a case where you would want to break out of an if-statement?

Comment: In my playground the break exits the scope of the `if` statement. You can solve all problems without breaking out of the `if` statement but it reads much nicer. In addition breaking out of `do` is even better in term of readability (added Example above).

Comment: I've learned a new thing today, regarding "guard" and escaping only from a specified scope. Cool!

Comment: After four years of Swift programming, I never knew there was a `do` statement (without `try`s)!

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old topic, but just now I used break and it was needed. 
So my example
I have array of objects. 
When user taps on a cell, i.parameter becomes True for the object in that cell.
I need to know when all the objects in the array have i.parameter = True , that's the condition to stop the game.

```
func forTimer(){
   for i in array {
    if i.parameter == false {
     break
  }
 }
}
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(forTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Even if one i.parameter = false, I do not need to check the rest of the array. 
This function is called every millisecond, so I will not have to check the whole array every millisecond.

Comment: The OP is asking for the use case of using `break`s on if statements, not for loops.

Comment: The 'break' is used in  if  nested loop not in for loop. I had not put the braces because i thought it is understandable. I have edited and added the braces.

Comment: Your break statement breaks the outer for, not the if statement inside. The OP asked about breaking an if statement.

Comment: The op asked "In what situation would one be using break in an if-statement? ", i have answered that. Please read the  question.  
 I do not think my answer from a year ago  deserves minus.